# ElasticSearch, filter locations where either longitude or latitude should be larger than 0

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, aggregate

What I try to achieve is an aggregation of geo_bounds. However, in the test database we got some strange values where the location might be negative (this isn't per say strange) which doesn't make sense in this case.

For some queries, this might result in a bounding box which covers another country which we are not expecting.

I would like to filter the geo_bounds aggregation where either longitude or latitude must be larger than 0.

I know that there is a filter for aggregations, as specified on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html but I am really not sure how to range check the longitude or latitude.

In our index model we got a structure where we have a location object which contains lon and lat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As negative values is valid for location, they're treated as valid by ES. So, 2 options here: validate data during indexing (way better IMO, but seems that its too late in your case) or filtering out points with negative location values in query.

The problem with on-the-fly filtering is that ES can actually filter geo-points with [4 filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/filter-by-geopoint.html) only. And this filters are not that cheap in terms of performance. You can use `geo_bounding_box` for your need, like this:

Index:

```
PUT so/_mapping/t1
{
  "t1": {
    "properties": {
      "pin": {
        "properties": {
          "location": {
            "type": "geo_point"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
POST so/t1
{
  "pin": {
    "location": {
      "lat": 10.1,
      "lon": 9.9
    }
  }
}
POST so/t1
{
  "pin": {
    "location": {
      "lat": 20.1,
      "lon": 99.9
    }
  }
}
POST so/t1
{
  "pin": {
    "location": {
      "lat": -10.1,
      "lon": -9.9
    }
  }
}
```

Query:

```
GET so/t1/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "plain": {
      "geo_bounds": {
        "field": "pin.location"
      }
    },
    "positive": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_bounding_box": {
          "pin.location": {
            "top_left": {
              "lat": 90,
              "lon": 0
            },
            "bottom_right": {
              "lat": 0,
              "lon": 180
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "bounds": {
          "geo_bounds": {
            "field": "pin.location"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "positive": {
         "doc_count": 2,
         "bounds": {
            "bounds": {
               "top_left": {
                  "lat": 20.1,
                  "lon": 9.9
               },
               "bottom_right": {
                  "lat": 10.1,
                  "lon": 99.9
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "plain": {
         "bounds": {
            "top_left": {
               "lat": 20.1,
               "lon": -9.9
            },
            "bottom_right": {
               "lat": -10.1,
               "lon": 99.9
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for :)